# Updating UICollectionViewFlowLayout when the height of my CollectionView changes during runtime

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `MyCollectionView` that has a constraint that is:

`BottomLayoutGuide.Top = MyCollectionView.Bottom + 100`

In my IB, but this constraint's constant changes according to the height of the keyboard

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let keyboardHeight = getKeyboardHeight(notification)
        keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + 20

        self.cardCollectionView.configureCollectionView()
        self.cardCollectionView.reloadInputViews()
    }
```

Where `configureCollectionView` is:

```
func configureCollectionView() {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // Create the layout
    let space = 10.0 as CGFloat
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let width = (self.frame.size.width) - 4 * space
    let height = (self.frame.size.height)

    let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2 * space, 0, 2 * space)

    // Set top and bottom margins if scrolling horizontally, left and right margins if scrolling vertically
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = space
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    // Set horizontal scrolling
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal

    // Set edge insets
    flowLayout.sectionInset = edgeInsets
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
    print(self.frame)
    print(flowLayout.itemSize)
    self.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)

    // Always allow it to scroll
    self.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true

}
```

Before the keyboard is shown, everything is fine and these are the values of the frame of `MyCollectionView` and it's `CollectionViewCell`

`self.frame: (0.0, 75.0, 375.0, 492.0)`

`flowLayout.itemSize: (335.0, 492.0)`

[image]

But after the keyboard is shown and `configureCollectionView()` is called which basically just resets the `flowLayout` for `MyCollectionView` everything breaks. And oddly, even though the height of `MyCollectionView` has decreased the console outputs says that it has actually increased.

`self.frame: (0.0, 55.0, 375.0, 512.0)`

`flowLayout.itemSize: (335.0, 512.0)`

Here is a screenshot after the keyboard has appeared:

[image]

As you can see, it seems like the `CollectionViewCells` are being clipped and it has lost it's initial alpha value. Moreover, after randomly scrolling the console outputs:

`2016-04-29 09:43:24.012 DeckWheel[15363:2028073] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-04-29 09:43:24.012 DeckWheel[15363:2028073] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.`

I know that this is due to the height of `MyCollectionView` changing but, I don't know why it is going wrong as everything works perfectly before the keyboard shows. For example, I can scroll randomly between the cells and if I get to the last cell it will automatically create a new one without any crashes.

I've tried `MyCollectionView.invalidateLayout()` and then calling`configureCollectionView()` to reset the `flowLayout` but nothing seems to work. What is the correct way to update `MyCollectionView` so that this does not happen?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?